# Invalid column name when trying to insert alphanumeric value into database

Tags: c#, sql

Basically, I have a some code that takes either an (1) alphanumeric or (2) numeric serial number and increments them. Everything works for the numeric serial numbers, but when I try to insert the alphanumeric serial number, it gives me the "invalid column name" error.

I've looked at a lot of the "invalid column name" posts here and none of them seem to answer my question. I've put breakpoints in and ran the code for both cases (numeric and alphanumeric) and I'm getting the same datatypes. Basically everything seems to line up correctly, so I'm at a loss.

The following code shows how I increment for both cases. Note that for the alphanumeric increment, I am calling a method IncrementAlphaNumeric, which takes the variable 'Output', which is the result of a SQL query that sorts the table and gets the last serial number.

```
// Increment Numeric Serial Numbers
if (isNum)
{
    int lastNumber = Int32.Parse(Output);
    int[] ints = Enumerable.Range(lastNumber + 1, printQuantity).Select(i => (int)i / 1).ToArray();
    increments = ints.Select(x => x.ToString()).ToArray();
    output.AppendText("Serial numbers to print: " + string.Join(", ", increments)); 
}

// Increment AlphaNumeric Serial Numbers
if (!isNum)
{
    for (int i = 0; i < printQuantity; i++)
    {
         increments[i] = IncrementAlphaNumeric(Output);
         snList.Add(increments[i]);
         Output = increments[i];
    }
    output.AppendText("Serial numbers to print: " + string.Join(", ", increments));
 }
```

Finally, I use Stringbuilder in order to insert the data into the database as follows:

```
// (5) Store new SNs in Database
StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
foreach (string newSns in increments)
{
    sb.AppendLine("INSERT INTO [Manufacturing].[dbo].[Device.Devices]([SerialNumber],[DeviceTypeID]) VALUES(" + newSns + "," + dType +")");
}

using (SqlCommand insertCommand = new SqlCommand(sb.ToString(), cnn))
{
    var executeNonQuery = insertCommand.ExecuteNonQuery();
}
```

Again, it works for numeric, but not for alphanumeric. When I put my breakpoints in and step through the code, the datatypes (Strings) are the same for each of the cases, numeric and alphanumeric.

The error message I'm getting is, again, "invalid column name". Basically, the expected results should be that the serial number, regardless of if it's numeric or alphanumeric, should be inserted into the correct table of the database, which is based on the device type (dType).

Comment: asked multiple times ... it's because string literals in SQL needs `'` ... but you should use [parameters](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.data.sqlclient.sqlparameter?view=netframework-4.8) instead to avoid [this](https://xkcd.com/327/)

Comment: I am not a C# user, but the explanation for why your insert fails for text values is that string literals in SQL take single quotes, e.g. `'data'`, not `data`.  But, _don't_ try to surround the data with quotes yourself.  Instead, learn how to use prepared statements from your C# code.

Comment: You have also the problem of multiple insert commands. They need to be separated by a semicolon at the end of each INSERT statement

Comment: Thanks for the quick replies. I'm still a little new to C#/SQL. The foreach/StringBuilder syntax would be where I parameterize the INSERT Query then?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As explained in comments, you should never concatenate strings to build your sql statement.
In your case I assume that you want to insert multiple records in your database using a single statement. This can be done also using parameters and manually building the VALUES part or your query (This syntax is available from Sql Server 2008)

```
// Sample values, replace them with your code that builds the increments array
string[] increments = new string[] {"VALUE1", "VALUE2","VALUE3", "VALUE4"};

// Invariant part of your query
string baseQuery = "INSERT INTO [Manufacturing].[dbo].[Device.Devices]([SerialNumber],[DeviceTypeID]) VALUES"; 

// Fixed value for the type 
string dType = "42";

List<SqlParameter> prms = new List<SqlParameter>();
List<string> placeHolders = new List<String>();

// Build a list of parameter placeholders and a list of those parameter and their values
for(int x = 0; x < increments.Length; x++)
{
    placeHolders.Add($"(@p{x},{dType})");
    prms.Add(new SqlParameter { ParameterName = $"@p{x}", SqlDbType = SqlDbType.NVarChar, Value = increments[x]});
}

// Put the text together
string queryText = baseQuery + string.Join(",", placeHolders);
// This should be the final text
// INSERT INTO [Manufacturing].[dbo].[Device.Devices]([SerialNumber],[DeviceTypeID])  
// VALUES(@p0,42),(@p1,42),(@p2,42),(@p3,42)


using (SqlCommand insertCommand = new SqlCommand(queryText, cnn))
{
    // Add all parameters to the command...
    insertCommand.Parameters.AddRange(prms.ToArray());
    var executeNonQuery = insertCommand.ExecuteNonQuery();
}
```

Comment: Thank you for your assistance. I understand now why you want to parameterize the SQL queries, which is what I was eventually going to do. Just wanted to get the business logic up-and-running to test the efficacy of the program I am creating.